# Handling nested formdata objects with Multer,express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

Multer works fine when the form data received is not nested.

**For example:** When the form data received is `photos:somePhotos` and the field is defined as: `{ name: "photos", maxCount: 1 }`

However, the problem now is that the client sends the photos inside a nested object using formData i.e `user[photos[0][photo]]`, where photos should be the array of files required.

So is it possible to do this using Multer?

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed explanation of your current frontend and backend setup with code examples.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?

Comment: No,I couldn't use out of the box multer to get the fields needed. I had to do it manually by decoding the entire object key string.For the example mentioned,I scan the string key `user[photos[0][photo]]` , and compare to a list of previously stored fields i am searching for i.e `['photos','profiles',]`. If the string key received matches one of the stored fields, the data is appended to the object storing all `photos`.All validation checks were also done manually. It is really messy, so if you can avoid sending nested data from the client do it, but in my case it was a must @HunterBecton

Comment: I ended up just using `upload.any()` to catch all the files and then handle them as needed.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same at the time. @HunterBecton